# When is a function strictly increasing?

Tags: integration, functions, graphing-functions

[image]

If I have a function, within an integral, how do I know if the function is strictly increasing for $x$ being greater than or equal to zero?

I thought maybe it might have something to do with the mean value theorem ?

Comment: b) is more about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f : I \rightarrow X$ is strictly increasing if for all $x,y \in I$ such that $x < y$, we have that $f(x) < f(y)$. See [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncreasingFunction.html) also for a condition on the derivative $f'$ of $f$ (assuming some conditions) which tells you if $f$ is increasing.

---

With regards to your edits, and added image, the result which I linked to becomes more important. So try differentiating the function $F(x)$. As mentioned in the comments, you'll need to think about the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. In general, this says that if we have (for $x \in [a,b]$)
$$ F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$$
then $F'(x)=f(x)$. So in our case, $F'(x) = e^x(x+1)^3$. Indeed, for $x \geq 0$, $F'(x) > 0$. Note that in the above link, we only get that this is increasing. For *strictly* increasing, we invoke [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2092267/252641) condition. But for our case, $F'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \geq 0$, so we have a strictly increasing function.

---

We can also do this more directly using the MVT; we can pick $a,b \in [0, x]$ such that $ a < b$. Then $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$. Then by the MVT, there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that 
$$ F'(c) = \frac{F(b) - F(a)}{b-a}.$$
As we've already shown, $F'(c) > 0$, and we know that $b-a>0$. Hence $F(b) - F(a) > 0 \implies F(b) > F(a) $. We can do this for all $a,b \in [0, x]$ with $a < b$, so $F$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: I get (t+1)²(t+4)e^t as a derivativee... but what about the x being greater than or equal to 0? what do i have to do with that part of the question ? plug in or somethign?

Comment: SHould i plug 0 in the derivative? if i do so i get 4, which is positive...

Comment: That's not correct for the derivative. See the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

Comment: I think it is.. did it on my calculator.. maybe i should expand

Comment: Oh im sorry... taking into consideration the theorem, then the derivative would be the function itself? Then i would only need to plug in 0 in the function intself? correct=

Comment: Moreover, why is the variable changing from t to x?

Comment: You just need to observe the the things I have written in the last paragraph of the answer. You don't need to plug a specific value in. For the variable question, you should study the proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, and some examples.

Comment: One more thing.. for it to be STRICTLY increasing, a necessary condition is that the derivative musto NOT be equal to zero?

Comment: [This](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Positive_derivative_implies_increasing) is perhaps a simpler version of the result, which deals with "strictly" straight away.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Differentiate the function. What do you get? What is the sign of the resulting function?

Comment: I get (t+1)²(t+4)e^t....

Comment: Then you made a mistake, because $F'(x)=e^x(x+1)^3$.

Comment: Why would the variable be x, pardon me? Wouldn't the derivative of an integral according the the fundamental theorem of calculus be the function itself? And as it is asking to see if it is strictly increasing at x being greater than or equal to zero, woulnd't i need to plug 0 in ?

Comment: The exercise is about $F(x)$. As you can see, the variable is $x$, not $t$. ANd since $F'(x)>0$ for each $x$, $F$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: I'm okay up to taking the derivative, which as you stated, is ex(x+1)ˆ3. And as the question states that x is greater than or equal to zero, if i try , i should put values of x that are greater than or equal to zero in the derived function and see how the answer is positive? correct?

Comment: No. You just note that $x\geqslant0\implies e^x(x+1)^3>0$.

Comment: sorry, don't understand what you mean...

Comment: Like, for example, what if the question stated x to be greater or equal than 2? How would the answer change?

Comment: It would *not* change.

Comment: What is the difference between a strictly increasing and an increasing function?

Comment: Increasing means that $x<y\implies f(x)\leqslant f(y)$. Strictly increaing means that $x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)$.